# How to get full ID from asp.net control for <label>

Tags: c#, asp.net, accessibility

I'm trying to get apply the ID from an asp.net control for a `<label>`'s `for` property for accessibility. For some reason I can't get the full ID that .NET creates.

**HTML on ASPX Page**

```
<td>
  <label id="lblSelReport" runat="server" for="selReport">Select Report Type</label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="selReport" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

**What is rendered is:**

```
<td>
  <label id="AxMstr_ExMstr_bodyPlaceHolder_bodyPlaceHolder_lblSelReport" for="selReport">Select Report Type</label>
  <select name="AxMstr$ExMstr$bodyPlaceHolder$bodyPlaceHolder$selReport" id="AxMstr_ExMstr_bodyPlaceHolder_bodyPlaceHolder_selReport">
    ...
  </select>
</td>
```

I would think the `for` property of `<label>` would be `"AxMstr_ExMstr_bodyPlaceHolder_bodyPlaceHolder_selReport"` since I'm giving it the ID of the `DropDownList` control. Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Try with this `for="<%= selReport.ClientID %>"` on the label

Comment: Thanks, Enrique. I just tried but what was rendered was this: `<label id="AxMstr_ExMstr_bodyPlaceHolder_bodyPlaceHolder_lblSelReport" for="<%= selReport.ClientID %>">Select Report Type</label>`

Comment: try using single quotes `'` or without

Comment: Same things happens with single quotes (parser error without any quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Server controls all have a 'ClientID' property, which resolves to whatever messed up value .Net gives that control at runtime.  Something like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" />
<%= lblName.ClientID %>
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I did try that (the same suggestion above) but it's only rendering `for="<%= selReport.ClientID %>"` on the `<label>` element.

Comment: Can you post your markup in your question? Sounds like something we can help you work through, as ClientID is definitely the solution you're looking for, it's just a matter of getting it to resolve/render correctly.

Comment: At the very least you should be able to set the 'for' attribute of your label to the ClientID value of your drop down list via code behind.

Comment: I did update my question to show the HTML on the ASPX page.  I'll try it via the codebehind.

Comment: Using the codebehind worked, Matt! Thanks for the suggestion: `lblSelReport.Attributes.Add("for", selReport.ClientID);` I don't know why I couldn't do this on the .aspx page, `for="<%= selReport.ClientID %>` but I'm glad this works. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Yeah, sometimes the markup is tricky in terms of properly escaping characters, especially when trying to resolve something within a server control element.